# ECK (Elastic Cloud on Kubernetes) restart container without using kubectl delete

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, elastic-cloud

Is there a way to restart a Elasticsearch cluster without using `kubectl delete`?

The context is that I have no access to run any cli commands (including `kubectl` commands), I can only deploy yaml files through kustomize. I now want to install a plugin (ingest-attachment) in the existing container, but it only installs when the container is initialized.

With other kinds of deployments I can set `replica:0` then set it back to `1` to imitate a delete and restart but for `kind:Elasticsearch` I cannot set `nodeSets` count to `0`, otherwise it throws an error and cannot be deployed.

Is there any possible work around allowing me to install the plugin on the Elasticsearch container?

Below is the Elasticsearch yaml file:

```
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1 
kind: Elasticsearch 
metadata: 
  name: elastic-test
spec: 
  version: 7.11.1
  auth:
    roles:
    - secretName: elastic-roles-secret
    fileRealm:
    - secretName: elastic-filerealm-secret
  nodeSets: 
  - name: default
    count: 1 
    config:
      node.store.allow_mmap: false 
    volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: azure-pvc
      spec:
        storageClassName: ""
        accessModes:
        - ReadWriteMany
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 25Gi
        volumeName: elasticsearch-azure-pv
    podTemplate:
      spec:
        initContainers:
        - name: install-plugins
          command:
          - sh
          - -c
          - |
            bin/elasticsearch-plugin install --batch ingest-attachment
```

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use?

Comment: client version: v1.20.4, server version: v1.18.10

Answer (score 0):

After searching for solution for your issue, I am sorry to inform that for now restarting cluster without methods you mentioned seems to be impossible.

In [this article](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-restart-kubernetes-pods)  you can find those methods.

[Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-bundles-plugins.html) you can find custom configuration files and plugins for Elasticsearch.

See also: [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-enterprise/1.1/ece-restart-cluster.html) and [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/restart-cluster.html) guide.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to research my issue, but unfortunately I have already seen these resources before and cannot solve my problem.

Comment: Maybe did you try restarting your cluster using API Elasticsearch (precisly Node Lifecycle API)? [Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/put-shutdown.html#put-shutdown-api-example) the example.

Answer (score 0):

With ECK as the operator, you do not need to use rollout restart. Apply your updated Elasticsearch spec and the operator will perform rolling update for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to trigger a **manual rolling restart**, one that is not based on the YAML file spec change, since ECK Operator and the ElasticSearch CRD creates a StatefulSet per Node set. You can do:

```
kubectl rollout restart statefulset/<name-of-statefulset>
```

To get your statefulsets:

```
kubectl get statefulset
```